# how to handle xlsx file reading error ("assert tvalue is not None") using xlrd package?

Tags: python, excel

Below Python code is to read xls & xlsx file. Im facing a problem while reading an xlsx file. Error is "assert tvalue is not None"

```
--> workbook=xlrd.open_workbook("/home/perlzuser/sprint12/template.xlsx")
sheet=workbook.sheet_by_index(0)    
data=[[sheet.cell_value(r,c) for c in range(sheet.ncols)]for r in range (sheet.nrows)]
print " ::",data
```

My error:::

> /home/perlzuser/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd/xlsx.pyc
>   in do_row(self, row_elem)
>       723                     else:
>       724                         bad_child_tag(child_tag)
>   --> 725                 assert tvalue is not None
>       726                 self.sheet.put_cell(rowx, colx, XL_CELL_TEXT, tvalue, xf_index)
>       727             else:
>
> AssertionError:

How to resolve this issue in python?

Comment: Please add the full traceback, not just the error part you've copied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a work around to resolve assertion error:

**code:**

```
import xlrd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("/home/perlzuser/sprint12/template.xlsx")
wb.save("file_new.xlsx")
workbook=xlrd.open_workbook("file_name.xlsx")

sheet=workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

data=[[sheet.cell_value(r,c) for c in range(sheet.ncols)]for r in range (sheet.nrows)]

print "output:", data
```

---

**Code Explanation:**

- Here I'm using load_workbook to read the file and saving that file as file_new.xlsx.
- I'm just copying the actual xlsx file(template.xlsx) data into a new xlsx file(file_new.xlsx)

**Note:** This copied file_new.xlsx can only be read by python code. It will be not in human readable format but your code will read it. You can use those data to store into DB or to write into other files.